# Counting distinct dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this `dictionary (key,list)`

```
index={'chair':['one','two','two','two'],'table':['two','three','three']}
```

and i want this

```
#1. number of times each value occurs in each key. ordered descending
indexCalc={'chair':{'two':3,'one':1}, 'table':{'three':2,'two':1}}
#2. value for maximum amount for each key
indexMax={'chair':3,'table':2}
#3. we divide each value in #1 by value in #2 
indexCalcMax={'chair':{'two':3/3,'one':1/3}, 'table':{'three':2/2,'two':1/2}}
```

I think I should use lambda expressions, but can't come up with any idea how i can do that. Any help?

Comment: You want all 3 or just the final output?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede , i want all 3 dictionaries, indexCalc, indexMax, indexCalcMax.

Comment: Your original index can't contain that data, because the values are sets and sets must be unique. Do you mean to use lists instead?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I understand that if you put that in that way, that will transfer it to set, but for representation purpose i put it in that way. that is List actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define your values as lists correctly:

```
index = {'chair': ['one','two','two','two'], 'table': ['two','three','three']}
```

Then use `collections.Counter` with dictionary comprehensions:

```
from collections import Counter
```

> 1. number of times each value occurs in each key.

```
res1 = {k: Counter(v) for k, v in index.items()}
```

> 2. value for maximum amount for each key

```
res2 = {k: v.most_common()[0][1] for k, v in res1.items()}
```

> 3. we divide each value in #1 by value in #2

```
res3 = {k: {m: n / res2[k] for m, n in v.items()} for k, v in res1.items()}
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks. Will try to understand how above code works, that will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
index={'chair':{'one','two','two','two'},'table':{'two','three','three'}}
```

Problem:  `{}` is creating a set. So you should consider to  convert it into list.

Now coming to your  solution:

```
from collections  import Counter


index={'chair': ['one','two','two','two'],'table':['two','three','three']}
updated_index = {'chair': dict(Counter(index['chair'])), 'table': dict(Counter(index['table']))}
updated_index_2 = {'chair': Counter(index['chair']).most_common()[0][1], 'table': Counter(index['table']).most_common()[0][1]}
print(updated_index)
print(updated_index_2)
```

You can use python collections library, `Counter` to find the count without  writing any lambda function.

> {'chair': {'one': 1, 'two': 3}, 'table': {'two': 1, 'three': 2}}
>
> {'chair': 3, 'table': 2}

Comment: thanks for comment, updated it to be a list. Is there any generic vesion to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a mistake in how you created the `index` dict. You should have lists as the elements for each dictionary, you currently have sets. Sets are automatically deduplicated, so you will not be able to get a proper count from there.

You should correct index to be:

```
index={'chair':['one','two','two','two'],'table':['two','three','three']}
```

You can use the [Counter module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in Python 3, which is a subclass of the `dict` module, to generate what you want for each entry in `indexCalc`. A counter will create a dictionary with a key, and the number of times that key exists in a collection.

```
indexCalc = {k, Counter(v) for k, v in index}
```

`indexCalc` looks like this:

```
{'chair': Counter({'two': 3, 'one': 1}), 'table': Counter({'three': 2, 'two': 1})}
```

We can easily find the index that corresponds to the maximum value in each sub-dictionary:

```
indexMax = {k: max(indexCalc[k].values()) for k in indexCalc}
```

`indexMax` looks like this:

```
{'chair': 3, 'table': 2}
```

You can create `indexCalcMax` with the following comprehension, which is a little ugly:

```
indexCalcMax = {k: {val: indexCalc[k][val] / indexMax[k] for val in indexCalc[k]} for k in indexCalc}
```

which is a dict-comprehension translation of this loop:

```
for k in indexCalc:
  tmp = {}
  for val in indexCalc[k]:
    tmp[val] = indexCalc[k][val] / float(indexMax[k])
  indexCalcMax[k] = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is suboptimal, but I had to do it as a thought exercise:

```
indexCalc = {
    k: {key: len([el for el in index[k] if el == key]) for key in set(index[k])} 
    for k in index
}
```

Not exactly lambda, as suggested, but comprehensions... Don't use this code in production :) This answer is only partial, you can use the analogy and come up with the other two structures that you require.